# cloumnfilter not working jquery datatables in serverside preprocessing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Columanfilter is not working in datatables in server side preprocessing. Datatable with column search is not working.Below code is the sample code.Can please provide it in the jsdiddle or any other. Please help me. 
This is javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 drawDataTable = function()
    {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",
        "sPagination": "full_numbers",
         "bFilter": true,
        "oSearch":{
               "sSearch":"",
               "bRegex": false,
               "bSmart": true },
        "aoColumns":[
               {"bSearchable": true},
                null,
                null,
                null
               ]    
    })
        .columnFilter({         
        aoColumns: [{
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "text"
        },{
            type: "text"
        }]
        });
    }   

    drawDataTable();


} );
```

And this is Html code

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Extn.</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Extn.</th>

                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing your body in between your `thead` and `tfoot`:

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Position</td>
                    <td>Office</td>
                    <td>Extn.</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: When this code placed we do search it displays Processing... and it goes struck.@Zee Tee

Comment: Seems like there's a problem with your JSON data, have you looked at it for any errors?

Comment: You should use firebug to test the response from your JSON script. Otherwise you're doing this all in the dark.

Comment: There are no errors at the JSON data.Can you please provide the example.@Zee Tee

Comment: When you do a filter search, it is hitting your php script or whatever you're using to return data specific for that search. Have you set all that up?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the sSource value is not passed properly. sSource is basically the "ajax" url value in DataTables.js. My solution to this is to re-add the sSource back from the DataTable ajax value on line 796 in the columnFilter.js file:

```
sSource = sSource ? sSource : oTable.fnSettings().ajax;
```

So it would look something like:

```
oTable.fnSettings().fnServerData = function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
  sSource = sSource ? sSource : oTable.fnSettings().ajax;
  ....
}
```